# How to export to dict some properties of an object

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I have a python class which has several properties. I want to implement a method which will return some properties as a dict. I want to mark the properties with a decorator. Here's an example:

```
class Foo:
    @export_to_dict  # I want to add this property to dict
    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return 1

    @property # I don't want to add this propetry to dict
    def bar2(self):
        return {"smth": 2}

    @export_to_dict # I want to add this property to dict
    @property
    def bar3(self):
        return "a"

    @property
    def bar4(self):
        return [2, 3, 4]

    def to_dict(self):
        return ... # expected result: {"bar1": 1, "bar3": "a"}
```

One way to implement it is to set an additional attribute to the properties with the export_to_dict decorator, like this:

```
def export_to_dict(func):
    setattr(func, '_export_to_dict', True)
    return func
```

and to search for properties with the `_export_to_dict` attribute when `to_dict` is called.

Is there another way to accomplish the task?

Comment: What about making a class decorator with arguments the method identifiers to be stored in a dictionary (maybe as attribute instead of a method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marking each property forces `to_dict` to scan all methods/attributes on each invocation, which is slow and inelegant. Here's a self-contained alternative that keeps your example usage identical.

#### Keep a list of exported properties in a class attribute

By making `export_to_dict` a class, we can use [`__set_name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) (Python 3.6+) to get a reference of the Foo class and add a new attribute to it. Now `to_dict` knows exactly which properties to extract, and because the list is per-class, you can annotate different classes without conflict.

And while we're at it, we can make `export_to_dict` automatically generate the `to_dict` function to any class that has exported properties.

The decorator also restores the original property after the class is created, so the properties work as normal without any performance impact.

```py
class export_to_dict:
    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        if not hasattr(owner, '_exported_properties'):
            owner._exported_properties = []
            assert not hasattr(owner, 'to_dict'), 'Class already has a to_dict method'
            owner.to_dict = lambda self: {prop.__name__: prop(self) for prop in owner._exported_properties}
        owner._exported_properties.append(self.property.fget)

        # We don't need the decorator object anymore, restore the property.
        setattr(owner, name, self.property)

class Foo:
    @export_to_dict  # I want to add this property to dict
    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return 1

    @property # I don't want to add this propetry to dict
    def bar2(self):
        return {"smth": 2}

    @export_to_dict # I want to add this property to dict
    @property
    def bar3(self):
        return "a"

    @property
    def bar4(self):
        return [2, 3, 4]

    # to_dict is not needed anymore here!

print(Foo().to_dict())
{'bar1': 1, 'bar3': 'a'}
```

If you don't want to your Foo class to have an extra attribute, you can store the mapping in a static dict `export_to_dict.properties_by_class = {class: [properties]}`.

---

#### Properties with setters

If you need to support property setters, the situation is a bit more complicated but still doable. Passing `property.setter` through is not sufficient, because the setter replaces the getter and `__set_name__` is not called (they have the same name, after all).

This can be fixed by splitting the annotation process and creating a wrapper class for `property.setter`.

```py
class export_to_dict:
    # Used to create setter for properties.
    class setter_helper:
        def __init__(self, setter, export):
            self.setter = setter
            self.export = export

        def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
            self.export.annotate_class(owner)
            setattr(owner, name, self.setter)

    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property

    @property
    def setter(self):
        return lambda fn: export_to_dict.setter_helper(self.property.setter(fn), self)

    def annotate_class(self, owner):
        if not hasattr(owner, '_exported_properties'):
            owner._exported_properties = []
            assert not hasattr(owner, 'to_dict'), 'Class already has a to_dict method'
            owner.to_dict = lambda self: {prop.__name__: prop(self) for prop in owner._exported_properties}
        owner._exported_properties.append(self.property.fget)
        
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.annotate_class(owner)
        # We don't need the decorator object anymore, restore the property.
        setattr(owner, name, self.property)

class Foo:
    @export_to_dict  # I want to add this property to dict
    @property
    def writeable_property(self):
        return self._writeable_property

    @writeable_property.setter
    def writeable_property(self, value):
        self._writeable_property = value

foo = Foo()
foo.writeable_property = 5
print(foo.to_dict())
{'writeable_property': 5}
```

Comment: This will be an issue once there is more than one class that uses this - the use of a global is unjustified.

Comment: @hyit Good point, I've replaced the global list with an attribute on the class.

Comment: nice! The use of `__set_name__` is clever and simplifies this quite a lot :clap:

Comment: Notice there is a problem if you **first** call `to_dict()` before initialize the attributes which support the setter protocol. `f = Foo(); f.to_dict() -> Error!`

Comment: @cards It's an error, but I think that's expected. You're trying to get all properties from an object that has uninitialized properties.

Comment: Sure, I think that one way to fix it is to set a default identifier pattern for _all_ the attributes which support getter/setter protocol, like `_prop_name`, and then filter by `hastattr(obj, "_prop_name")`. By the way nice answer, learn a lot from it

Comment: ... but careful that this means also that you call `to_dict` only once you are **sure** that all properties are been initialized! And you have a lot of properties it could be a mess

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Only in **EDIT 3** and **EDIT 2** a full read/write protocol is implemented. In particular, **EDIT 2** has no "side effects" [see my comments to *BoppreH*'s answer].

---

[EDIT 3] custom property

If a full read/write/... protocol is desired then make your *property* by subclassing the build-in type `property`. Look at the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) for a full description of the standard implementation.

Then use the *custom* property, `PropertyTracker`, to track those methods that you need and use the default `property` for those you don't mind.

Here just an example and notice the `to_dict` is an attribute not a method and it is accessible only once a *custom* property is explicitly triggered.

```
class PropertyTracker(property):

    PROPERTY_TRACKER_ID = 'to_dict' # it will be an attribute (not a method!) of the target class

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):       
        value = super().__get__(obj, objtype)
        
        if not hasattr(obj, self.PROPERTY_TRACKER_ID):
            setattr(obj, self.PROPERTY_TRACKER_ID, {})

        getattr(obj, self.PROPERTY_TRACKER_ID).update({self.fget.__name__: value})
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        super().__set__(obj, value)

        p_name =  self.fget.__name__
        getattr(obj, self.PROPERTY_TRACKER_ID).update({p_name: value})


class Foo:

    @PropertyTracker #    I want to add this property to dict
    def bar1(self):
        return 1

    @property #         I don't want to add this propetry to dict
    def bar2(self):
        return {"smth": 2}

    @PropertyTracker #    I want to add this property to dict
    def bar3(self):
        return self._bar3

    @bar3.setter
    def bar3(self, v):
        self._bar3 = v

    @property
    def bar4(self): #   I don't want to add this propetry to dict
        return [2, 3, 4]


f = Foo()
# print(f.to_dict) # <- will raise an error, "to_dict" doesn't exist yet!
f.bar1 #             <- after calling a method decorated with the custom property the "to_dict" will become available 
f.bar2
print(f.to_dict)
#{'bar1': 1}
f.bar3 = 3
print(f.to_dict)
#{'bar1': 1, 'bar3': 3}
f.bar3 = 333
print(f.to_dict)
#{'bar1': 1, 'bar3': 333}
```

---

[EDIT 2] class decorator + combo method decorator decorating class properties, Python >= 3.8.

Support read/write protocol *without* any side-effects.

Initialisation time line

1. decorator's `__init__`
2. decorator's methods `record`s
3. decorator's `__call__`
4. update `dict`
5. instance' setters and getters

```
class PropertyReader:
    # add "to_dict" method and "_recorded_props" to the target class

    def __init__(self):
        self._recorded_props = {}

    def record(self, prop) -> property:
        self._recorded_props[prop.fget.__name__] = None # default value
        return prop

    def __call__(self, target_cls):
        # dynamically add "to_dict" method and "recorded_props" attr
        setattr(target_cls, self.to_dict.__name__, self.to_dict)        
        setattr(target_cls, '_recorded_props', self._recorded_props)

        # apply getter/setter decorations to the target class
        for prop_name in self._recorded_props:
            self.decorated_descriptors(target_cls, prop_name)

        return target_cls

    @staticmethod
    def to_dict(target_cls) -> dict:
        # don't show the attributes set to None
        return {k: v for k, v in target_cls._recorded_props.items() if v is not None}
        return target_cls._recorded_props # all key-value pairs, also those with None

    @staticmethod
    def setter_wrapper(prop):
        # setter wrapper to be applied to
        def __setter_wrapper(target_cls, v):
            prop.fset(target_cls, v)
            target_cls._recorded_props.update({prop.fget.__name__: v})
        return __setter_wrapper

    @classmethod
    def decorated_descriptors(cls, target_cls, prop_name) -> None:
        # add to the decorated class the new getter/setter
        prop = getattr(target_cls, prop_name)
        if prop.fset:
            setattr(target_cls, prop_name, prop.setter(cls.setter_wrapper(prop)))
        else:
            target_cls._recorded_props.update({prop_name: prop.fget(target_cls)})


@(prop:=PropertyReader()) # walrus decoration
class Foo:

    @prop.record
    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return 1

    @property
    def bar2(self):
        return {"smth": 2}

    @prop.record
    @property
    def bar3(self):
        return self._bar3

    @bar3.setter
    def bar3(self, v):
        self._bar3 = v


f = Foo()
print(f.to_dict())
#{'bar1': 1}
f.bar1
f.bar3 = 333
print(f.to_dict())
#{'bar1': 1, 'bar3': 333}
f.bar3 = 300
print(f.to_dict())
#{'bar1': 1, 'bar3': 300}
f.bar3 = 333
print(f.to_dict())
#{'bar1': 1, 'bar3': 333}
```

---

[EDIT 1] class decorator with parameters decorating properties of a class.

The decorator dynamically adds an instance method `to_dict` to a class.

```
class PropertyReader:
    # add "to_dict" method to a class

    @staticmethod
    def meta_to_dict(target_cls, prop_dict):
        # contains a function that will be the method of the class 
        def to_dict(self):
            # method of the instance
            return {k: prop(self) for k, prop in prop_dict.items()}
        setattr(target_cls, to_dict.__name__, to_dict)
    
    def __init__(self, *method_names):
        self.method_names = method_names

    def __call__(self, cls):
        # filter attributes by property and identifier
        props_dict = {} # dictionary of callable getters
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if isinstance(attr, property):
                if attr_name in self.method_names:
                    props_dict[attr_name] = attr.fget # callable!

        # bind method to the class
        self.meta_to_dict(cls, props_dict)
        return cls

@PropertyReader('bar1', 'bar3')
class Foo:
   ...

print(Foo().to_dict())
```

---

[Original] Using a function to decorate a class.

```
def export_to_dict(*method_names):

    def __wrapper(cls):

        def meta_to_dict(prop_dict):
            # contains a function that will be the method of the class 
            def to_dict(self):
                # method of the instance
                return {k: prop(self) for k, prop in prop_dict.items()}
            setattr(cls, to_dict.__name__, to_dict)

        # filter attributes by property and identifier
        props_dict = {}
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if isinstance(attr, property):
                if attr_name in method_names:
                    props_dict[attr_name] = attr.fget # callable!
        
        # bind method to the class
        meta_to_dict(props_dict)

        return cls
    return __wrapper


@export_to_dict('bar1', 'bar3')
class Foo:
    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return 1

    @property # I don't want to add this propetry to dict
    def bar2(self):
        return {"smth": 2}

    @property
    def bar3(self):
        return "a"

    def bar4(self):
        return [2, 3, 4]


f = Foo()
print(f.to_dict())
# {'bar1': 1, 'bar3': 'a'}
```

The decorator could be made "prettier" by using a class to avoid difficult to read nested functions' declaration.

Comment: Good approach, but I'm not a fan of writting method's or property's name as a strings. It makes refactoring and search of usage more difficult.

Comment: I agree, but has the advantage of a single decoration. Do you want to manually decorate each method (as in your code sample)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally go with your original approach. I think it's the cleanest and involves least amount of future maintenance:

```py
import inspect

EXPORTABLE = "_exportable"

def export_to_dict(prop):
    if prop.fget:
        setattr(prop.fget, EXPORTABLE, True)
    return prop

class Foo:
    @export_to_dict
    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return 1

    @property
    def bar2(self):
        return {"smth": 2}

    @export_to_dict
    @property
    def bar3(self):
        return "a"

    @property
    def bar4(self):
        return [2, 3, 4]

    def to_dict(self):
        statics = {inspect.getattr_static(self, prop) for prop in dir(self)}
        props = {prop for prop in statics if isinstance(prop, property) and prop.fget is not None}
        return {prop.fget.__name__: prop.fget(self) for prop in props if hasattr(prop.fget, EXPORTABLE)}
```

Comment: OP did ask for alternative solutions, but I agree this is the cleanest approach. Consider caching the property inspection, instead of scanning the class on every `to_dict` call.

Answer (score 0):

If using [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) is an option for you, it enables a quite concise solution:

```
import attrs

EXPORT_METADATA = '__export_metadata'


def my_field(default=attrs.NOTHING, validator=None, repr=True, eq=True, order=None, hash=None, init=True,
             metadata=None, converter=None, export=False):
    metadata = metadata or {}
    metadata[EXPORT_METADATA] = export
    return attrs.field(default=default, validator=validator, repr=repr, eq=eq, order=order, hash=hash, init=init,
                       metadata=metadata, converter=converter)


def export_filter(attribute, value):
    return attribute.metadata.get(EXPORT_METADATA, False)


@attrs.frozen
class Foo:
    bar1 = my_field(default=1, init=False, export=True)
    bar2 = my_field(default={"smth": 2}, init=False)
    bar3 = my_field(default="a", init=False, export=True)
    bar4 = my_field(default=[2, 3, 4], init=False)

    def to_dict(self):
        return attrs.asdict(self, filter=export_filter)


print(Foo().to_dict())
```

Adapted from attrs's [metadata example](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/extending.html#extending-metadata).

Comment: This solution would be hard to use if properties are not just constants, but contain some calculations.

Answer (score 0):

### Without decorators

#### No codegen (loop every call)

```py
class Exportable:
    export_to_dict = ()

    def to_dict(self):
        return {prop: getattr(self, prop) for prop in self.export_to_dict}


class Foo(Exportable):
    export_to_dict = ["bar1", "bar2"]

    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return 1

    @property  # I don't want to add this propetry to dict
    def bar2(self):
        return {"smth": 2}

    @property
    def bar3(self):
        return "a"

    @property
    def bar4(self):
        return [2, 3, 4]


assert Foo().to_dict() == {"bar1": 1, "bar2": {"smth": 2}}
```

#### With codegen (no extra loop)

Replace `Exportable` with the following:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c

class Exportable:
    export_to_dict = ()

    def to_dict(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.to_dict = c(
            {prop: c.attr(prop) for prop in cls.export_to_dict}
        ).gen_converter()
```

Under the hood, `gen_converter` generates the following code, which contains no loops:

```py
def converter(data_):
    try:
        return {"bar1": data_.bar1, "bar2": data_.bar2}
    except __exceptions_to_dump_sources:
        __convtools__code_storage.dump_sources()
        raise
```